# Server side rendering with EJS

Tags: html, node.js

I think I have a misunderstanding of server side rendering with ejs.

Per my understanding, when we create an ejs template and do

```
res.render('home.ejs')
```

The entire page is created in the server side. The page will contain all of the images and libraries pre loaded. This is then sent to the browser where the DOM event handler javascript code is run

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

What is ejs: Point we should focus to understand ejs: EJS makes easy to write HTML and just that, nothing more, nothing less.

How it works:In general we can not write plain javascript inside html but through ejs we can do that. Previously we have to organize javascript code but now we don't need to be panic about it. Just write plain javascript inside html.

Hence you said 'The entire page is created in the server side' is actually a wrong statement.  Thank you so much.